# docker container exits out immediately with a script attached

Tags: docker

I'm trying to add a script to a docker run command , command i'm using is :

```
docker run -dit --name 1.4  ubuntu  sh -c 'echo "Input website:"; read website; echo "Searching.."; sleep 1; curl http://$website;'
```

and then install curl , then enter a website as input and it should reply to me as per the course i'm studying , but running this exact command makes the container exit immediately

any guidance on why would that be ?
also how should i send the input to the container so it can use it afterwards , do i just attach to it after installing curl in the terminal ?

Comment: You can try running the container first with in detach mode with -d flag and run and dummy command like sleep e.g. `docker run -d --name 1.4 ubuntu sleep 600`
and then use the `exec`  to run your commands e.g.
`docker exec -it 1.4 sh -c 'echo "Input website:"; read website; echo "Searching.."; sleep 1; curl http://$website;'`

Comment: If your main container process needs to read from its stdin, running it in the background with `docker run -d` seems like it will interfere with using it.  Does removing that option help?  Does the container in fact exit, or just the `docker run` command?  How exactly do you install `curl`, it's not present in the base `ubuntu` image?

Comment: @Waqas yeah when i try that i still get only the word Input as output which is the same as i was getting before , do you have any idea how am i supposed to input the website for the read command ?

Comment: @DavidMaze I install curl by getting into the terminal of the docker and sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade and sudo apt install curl , doing it without the -d tag i get only the word Input after running directly and the container exits directly

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to recommend an extremely different workflow from what you suggest.  Rather than manually installing software and trying to type arguments into the stdin of a shell script, you can build this into a reusable Docker image and provide its options as environment variables.

In comments you describe a workflow where you first start a container, then get a debugging shell inside of it, and then install `curl`.  Unless you're really truly debugging, this is a pretty unusual workflow: anything you install this way will get lost as soon as the container exits, and you'll have to repeat this step every time you re-run the container.  Instead, create a new empty directory, and inside that create a file named `Dockerfile` (exactly that name, no extension, capital `D`) containing

```bash
# Start our new image from this base
FROM ubuntu

# Install any OS-level packages we need
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \  # avoid post-installation questions
    apt-get install \
      --no-install-recommends \       # don't install unneeded extra packages
      --assume-yes \                  # (-y) skip an "are you sure" prompt
      curl
```

Rather than try to read from the container's input, you can take the URL as an environment variable.  In most cases the best way to give the main command to a container is by specifying it in the Dockerfile.  You can imagine running a larger script or program here as well, and it would take the some environment-variable setting (using Python's `os.environ`, Node's `process.env`, Ruby's `ENV`, *etc.*).

In our case, let's make the main container command be the single `curl` command that you're trying to run.  We haven't specified the value of the environment variable yet, and that's okay: this shell command isn't evaluated until the container actually runs.

```bash
# at the end of the Dockerfile
CMD curl "$website"
```

Now let's build and run it.  When we do launch the container, we need to provide that `$website` environment variable value, which we can do with a `docker run -e` option.

```bash
# Build the image:
docker build \
  -t my/curl  # giving it a name
  .           # using the content in the current directory

docker run \
  --rm        # deleting the container when done
  -e website=https://stackoverflow.com \
  my/curl     # with the same name as above
```

So note that we're starting the container in the foreground (no `-d` option) since we want to see its output and we expect it to exit promptly; we're cleaning up the container when it's done; we're not trying to pass a full shell script as a command-line argument; and we are providing our options on the command line, so we don't need to make the container's stdin work (no `-i` or `-t` option).

A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process.  When that process exits, the container exits too.  In this example, the thing you want the container to do is run a `curl` command; that's not a long-running process, hence `docker run --rm` but not `-d`.  There's not an "afterwards" here, if you need to query a different Web site then launch a new container.  It's very normal to destroy and recreate containers, especially since there are many options that can only be specified when you first start a container.

With the image and container we've built here, in fact, it's useful to think about them as analogous to the `/usr/bin/curl` binary on your host.  You build it once into a reusable artifact (here the Docker image), and you run multiple instances of it (`curl` commands or new Docker containers) giving options on the command line at startup time.  You do not typically "get a shell" inside a `curl` command-line invocation, and I'd similarly avoid `docker exec` outside of debugging tasks.

Comment: yeah that worked great ,that seems  a lot cleaner , just an extra question , if i still wanted to accept it through container input while also using the image from the Dockerfile , What would i do ?

Comment: Try writing your `read ... curl` sequence into an ordinary shell script; run and test it without Docker.  `COPY` the script into your image, and then make the main container `CMD` be to run the script.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `alpine/curl` image to use `curl` command without needing to install anything.

First start the container in detached mode with `-d` flag.
Then run your script with `exec` sub command.

```
docker run -d --name 1.4 alpine/curl sleep 600 
docker exec -it 1.4 sh -c 'echo "Input website:"; read website; echo "Searching.."; sleep 1; curl http://$website;'
```

[image]